# Monstera has small spots, do i have to worry?

Tags: monstera

I have found these weird tiny pale/white spots on my monstera and I am not sure why they are there and if they're a problem in the first place.

Important to note is that these spots do not go away when I rub over them with my finger, nor did the motherplant have thrips so I am not sure what it is and if it is even a reason to worry.

[image: Monstera leaf with white markings]

[image: Underside of the leaf]

I have had the plant for probably half a year. A friend of a friend did propagate his plant and gave me a small sapling.

I just noticed the problem so I'm not sure how long it has been going on. Though I did notice it on other leaves too.

The monstera stands on the windowsill (inside) so it does get quite a bit of sunlight. It is winter now though so it probably didn't get as much and it is quite cold in our apartment.

I did water her whenever her soil dried fully in the summer and when it was still warm. Now when it got cold I started watering her much rarer. I usually water  about a cup at once I think? And yes the pot does have a drainage hole.